# Relative SourceURI not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I cannot figure out a relative path that works for my resource. I've tried everything I could think of. The only thing that works is an absolute path that is only correct on my system, but would be incorrect in any deployed version.

As far as I know, this very simple path should work.

```
public class GreyscaleEffect : ShaderEffect
{
    private static PixelShader _pixelShader = new PixelShader()
        { UriSource = new Uri("/Effects/Greyscale.ps", UriKind.Relative) };
```

For which I get the error `The type initializer for 'FSR.WPF.Utilities.UI. GreyscaleEffect' threw an exception.` Inner Exception: `Cannot locate resource 'effects/greyscale.ps'.`

I've also tried the following:

```
Uri(";component/Effects/Greyscale.ps", UriKind.Relative)
Uri("/;component/Effects/Greyscale.ps", UriKind.Relative)
Uri("/FSR.WPF.Utilities.UI;component/Effects/Greyscale.ps", UriKind.Relative)
```

Elsewhere (in a xaml file in MUSUI), the following path is used, and it works fine:

```
<Image Source="/FSR.WPF.Utilities.UI;component/assets/CurrencyFlags/USD.png"
```

So I can't figure out why this case, which is so similar, doesn't work.

Only the following absolute path works:

```
Uri("C:\TFS\MUS 6.1.x\Mosaic Middleware\FSR.WPF.Utilities\FSR.WPF.Utilities.UI" +
    "\Effects\Greyscale.ps")
```

I've also tried all of the above with every combination of using `@` in front of the string, using UriKind.Absolute, and leaving out the second parameter altogether. Nothing works but the absolute path and I'm losing my mind.

Here's the solution structure. The Main project is MUSUI, at the bottom in bold. This effect class and .ps file are both in the Effects folder which is at the root of a referenced assembly FSR.WPF.Utilities.UI.

[image]

Anyways, I know this has to work somehow. Anyone that can figure out the shortest working relative path possible, especially if it doesn't require hard-coding in the assembly name, gets the prize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't specify a relative URI, it must be absolute. When you specify a relative URI in XAML, it is actually converted into an absolute URI using [`IUriContext.BaseUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.iuricontext.baseuri.aspx), but in C# code there is no information about the current location, so you can't use a relative URI.

You need to specify the URI by using the [`pack://` URI scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx):

```
UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourAssembly;component/Effects/Greyscale.ps");
```

Comment: Mind blown. Using this path fixed it. Now, in the event that this utility library's assembly name changes, is there a way to format this path such that is uses the 'assembly the current class belongs to', since GreyscaleEffect.cs and Greyscale.ps are always going to be in the same place?

Comment: @Alain, yes, you can use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` to get the current assembly

Comment: Ohh I love the way Intellisense misses this, it does not sense this at all, tells nothing so everyone who fell into this trap(depending on their luck) will waste couple of hours in rechecking and trial workarounds until reaching this solution. TY TY TY! THIS IS SPARTASOFT!!! not Microsoft

Comment: @EpiGen, I think you're barking at the wrong tree.... Intellisense has nothing to do with it, and I wouldn't expect it to spot the issue.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque As you bark in intelligent manner that I don know what is the purpose of Intellisense. At time I wrote I was mad cz lost several hours, was mad because of this "in C# code there is no information about the current location" and none of the references warn about this

Answer (score 0):

I think this is WPF's PixelShader class bug, because PixelShader don't implement IUriContext interface which can persist the BaseUri context, while System.Windows.Controls.Image & System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink & System.Windows.ResourceDictionary, etc. implement IUriContext, so they can use relative Uri

To enable PixelShader relative Uri sensitive, can use a Hyperlink as a redirector, for example

```
    <Window>
    <Window.Resources>
    <Hyperlink x:Key="ItemForRedirectKey" NavigateUri="{Your PixelShader.ps relative uri}" TargetName="{Binding Path= NavigateUri,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <PixelShader x:Key="PixelShaderKey" UriSource={Binding Path=TargetName,Source={StaticResouce ItemForRedirectKey}   }/>
    </Window.Resources>
    </Window>
```